# while loop, really don't understand

Tags: c++, loops

hi im trying to do a while loop, im new to programming and reading online i cant really get my head around it, i have used flag to show that the inputted name matches the name in the data file, i want to do this so that after i know it doesnt match it loops it the whole thing again, i have no clue how to implement this,

```
{

    clrscr();
    cout << "This Is The Option To Delete A Record\n";
    char yesno;
    char search;
    char name[21];
    int flag = 0;
    cout << "Enter Employee Name : ";

    Input(name,20);

    for (int r=0;r<row;r++)
    {

    if( strnicmp(name, emp[r].first_name, strlen(name) ) == 0 )
        {

            flag = 1;
            clrscr();
            cout << "Employee Number - " << emp[r].employee_number << endl;
            cout << "Name - " << emp[r].first_name << " " << emp[r].surname << endl;
            cout << "Department Number - " << emp[r].department_number << endl;
            cout << "Week Ending Date - " << emp[r].weekend << endl;


            cout << "Delete This Record (Y/N)? : ";
            Input(yesno);
            yesno = tolower(yesno);

            if ( yesno == 'y' )
            {
                emp[r].deleted = true;
                cout << "Record Has Been Deleted";
            }
            else if ( yesno == 'n') 
            {
                cout << "Record Hasn't Been Deleted";
            }
        }

    }

    if (flag == 0)
    {
    cout << "There Are No Matching Records" << endl;
    }
    pressKey();
}
```

Comment: If your question is about a `while` loop, shouldn't the code you post contain the keyword `while` somewhere?

Comment: And refactor your code, move sections into functions that have meaning to you and call them. That's way easier to spot the errors.

Comment: Are you thinking of the `continue` keyword?

Comment: I recommend you refer to any introductory C/C++ programming book. You can find your answer in **any** of the books.

Comment: is row defined somewhere?

Comment: I recommend you get rid of `clrscr()`.  You will not be able to see any of the previous history for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple, so have a bunch of code you want to keep executing it while a flag is zero, so that's just

```
int flag = 0;
while (flag == 0)
{
    // whole bunch of code
}
```

That's it, just replace 'whole bunch of code' with the code you've written above.

Comment: don't forgot to get out of the loop by changing the value of flag

Comment: @RSFalcon7 Of course but the OP is already setting that flag in the code he's written.

Comment: haha... I didn't know what [OP](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79804/whats-stackexchange-ese-for-op) extends for ;)

Comment: im confused how can flag be set before youve run the rest of the code?

Comment: @user2355072 Since the while loop tests the flag as the very first thing it does you *must* set it to something. Since you want the while loop to execute at least once you must set it to zero. If you set it to anything else the while loop wouldn't execute at all because `flag == 0` would be false.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing this in a `while` loop would look like this:

```
bool flag=false;
while(!flag){
    ...
    if(<find a match>) flag=true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so basically, you have a file with some data. And also, you accept some data from the user.
And then you perform a comparison between the appropriate fields of the two sets.

Why would you want to do it all over again once the entire comparison (file process) is done?

if you simply want to run an infinite loop, you can do this:

```
while(true)
{
   //your code
}
```

you can do same with a for loop also. infact for loop and while loop both are same except for the syntax. i.e. an infinite for loop.

```
for (int r=0;r<row;r++)
{
        if(r==row-1)
        {
             r=0;
        }
}
```

I guess what you want to do is to, once one set of user input doesn't match the file content, you want to take another set and match it again and so on.

so you don't need an infinite or always executing loop for this.

Just make your comparison module a separate function which should accept the set of user inputs. All you do is accept user inputs and show the result. And give the user an option to re-enter inputs.

Below is simple algo for what you want.

```
  int main()
  {
      char a='a';
      while(a != '~')
      {
          TakeUserInput();   

          if(PerformComparison())
          {
             cout << "Success"; 
             break;
          }
      }    
  }
```

inside `TakeUserInput()` you do all those `cin <<` to set a global array or set of global variable. also, you `cin << a`, to terminate program at your will.

and inside PerformComparison(), you do what you have posted here in your question.

Comment: im really new to c++, what i want to do is if i enter something that doesnt match the data in the data file it will loop the procedure again

Comment: so that means, you want to run entire "take user input" and "perform comparison" flow again? then that's what i said in the answer. take user input and pass it to a separate function which compares. if it returns true, take the user input again

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you understand the `for` loop, I think you can understand the `while` loop quite easily based on the comparison of `for` and `while`.

See, you used a `for` loop:

```
for (int r=0;r<row;r++){
   // do stuff
}
```

There are 3 key points here.

1. `int r=0` This is your initial condition.
2. `r<row` This is your condition which keeps the loop running.
3. `r++` This is what happens at the end of each iteration of loop.

To rephrase the statements above:

> Considering `r` equals zero initially, while `r` is less than `row`, increment `r`.

Now we can easily see how `while` loop is striking us:) To implement this, consider the following `while` loop example:

```
int r=0;        //(1)
while(r<row){   //(2)
    //do stuff
    r++;        //(3)
}
```

See, now the 2 loops do practically the same thing.

If you want to do operations based on a flag, you can also prefer an infinite loop:

```
while(1==1){
    if(some condition)
        break;
}
```

as well as an infinite `for` loop:

```
for(;;){
    if(if some condition)
        break;
}
```

Again, 2 loops are practically the same.